# Pimcore Import / Export

Tags: pimcore

I am creating a new site in pimcore. Is there a way to export / import full data for a pimcore site so that I can export pimcore data in xml / csv format make necessary changes and then import it back?

Answer (score 8):

There is a CSV export/import option in Pimcore:

- click on the object folder and then you will see **CSV export** button in top right of the tab
- to import the CSV data you need to right click on the folder and use the **CSV import** option
- to just update existing objects check the **Overwrite** option in the CSV import wizard

Please keep in mind these things:

- the Pimcore allows for very complex data relations and very complex data types
- it is very hard or even impossible to describe all the different data types and relations in an CSV file
- exporting and reimporting might cause a loss of data in some cases
- to make import and export really stable, you should write your own exporter and importer which takes some understanding of Pimcore and programming knowledge

CSV export/import might be good enough for your needs, but be careful and do backups before doing big changes.

Answer (score 1):

check if your csv file size is less than 2 mb bcaz if it's not you will get error while Importing and also let me know if you know the trick to import the csv file more than of 2 mb

Answer (score -1):

Hi you need to change the configuration in php.ini file.

After you open this file edit the following:

- `upload_max_filesize=2M` to `upload_max_filesize=10M`

This will allow you to upload upto 10M

Comment: Does not answer the question "is there a way to export/import", but this answer comes first in the page for some reason. Igor Benko's answer is better, gives more insights about the capabilities and limitations of Pimcore.